# convert vmdk to ova using ovftool

Tags: vmware, vmware-player, vmdk

I am trying to convert vmdk file to ova uisng ovftool

This is the command I type.

```
 C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware OVF Tool>ovftool -st=vmdk "C:\Windows Server 2016\win2trg1-1.vmdk" -tt=ova "C:\Windows Server 2016\win2trg1-1.ova"
```

However it did not work. The error is found below.

```
Error: Failed to parse option '-st=vmdk'. Reason: Source type not known: vmdk
Completed with errors
```

I am using windows 8 cmd and I did get help from this link.
[convert VMX to OVF using OVFtool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715081/convert-vmx-to-ovf-using-ovftool). It did not work

Any solutions?

Comment: Try to find VMX file and use it to convert

Answer (score 8):

Try this command:

`ovftool [original .vmx location and filename] [new .ova location and filename]`

**Example:**

`ovftool test_machine.vmx test_machine.ova`

If you don't have .vmx then you can also say

`ovftool test_machine.ovf test_machine.ovf`

Answer (score 2):

If you have VMware Workstation, you can open your VM (the `.vmx` file) and use `File > Export to OVF...`. This will create an OVF file that you can use in VirtualBox.

According to [this post](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2197285#2197285), an OVA file is just a TAR archive containing the OVF package files. So you could do it by hand.

Comment: Do you need the Pro version? You do for VMware Fusion.